# header not complying to 100% width

Tags: javascript, html, css

kindly check out this website:

http://www.imageworkz.asia/cranium

try resizing the window so small to the point that a horizontal scrollbar appears. Drag the horizontal scrollbar to the right and then the problem occurs. The header and footer does not seem to adjust accordingly. In the css, the header and footer element has a 100% width.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: All of these answers are (in part) correct, but applying each of these fixes still resulted in the bug you mentioned. Your basic problem is that your nav (and ancestor) elements aren't expanding to the width and placement of the huge central image. There are a number of factors, but the suspicious part to me is the -prefix-origin-transform applied to that `img`

Comment: @AJ Naidas i have seen your markup there lot things you have to change in your code so check carefully step by step from top to bottom you will get it your result smoothly due to lack of time i m not able to giving u the solution so its not hard just see the code carefully and modifiy the code....in header with logo-panel id you should play there with float and use position absolute in header and make parent of logo-panel with margin-auto etc.. so there are lot of things u have to do....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how 100% width works. The width of the element is the same as the parent element, and as there is a scroll bar it's narrower than the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an issue, but if you want the header to resize, I suggest using media queries to adjust based on screen size.

[Media Query Examples](http://mediaqueri.es/)

Answer (score 0):

Your article element has a fixed width so it overflows the container when the container shrinks.  You could try floating your container div, that should make sure that it doesn't shrink.

```
<div id="container" style="display: block; float: left">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS3 multiple background images to the `'body'` elements and then use CSS3 PIE to make it work in IE http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-background

```
body{
    background: url("/cranium/img/2 MAIN/bg.jpg") repeat 0 40px, url(headerbg.png) repeat-x left top, url(footerbg.png) repeat-x left bottom;
    -pie-background: url("/cranium/img/2 MAIN/bg.jpg") repeat 0 40px, url(headerbg.png) repeat-x left top, url(footerbg.png) repeat-x left bottom;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

Remember `-pie-background` is **relative to HTML, not to CSS**
This will definitely solve your problem.